# How to save and retrieve appointments on a silver-light application?

Tags: database, silverlight, telerik, scheduler

I am new in developing silver-light application, so I decide to practice on making a small scheduler for a friend  and for practice. I found [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) which provide templates grids, charts, and what not.So I used their calendar template and I was able to edit appointments and create new appointments but I can not save them because it is not connected to a database. Being that I am novice in programming as a whole! I have no idea where to start to solve this problem. I am not asking people to do my work just point me at the right direction.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different sides to this. The storage part and the part where you plug in your system into the Telerik appointments system.

First the storage issue, you should try to find something that stores stuff locally. If you know some SQL, I'd recommend [SQL Lite](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/#/). (Edit, since I missed you were using Silverlight, [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) is one of many alternatives)

If you don't want to use SQL you'll have to store it in another way, like a plain text file that you write to "on save" and parse when loading up your application.

The second part is trying to get the information from and into the Telerik system. [This page](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-data-binding-support-overview.html) explains what you should aim for. I'd look into the "AppointmentsSource". Also, I recommend looking into the MVVM-approach, since that makes it a lot easier to disconnect the view from your storage logic.